# React-router causes Cannot read property 'listen' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I faced strange js exception when rendered webpack build with `react-router` on the server side:

```
Cannot read property 'listen' of undefined
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`browserHistory` is the code resulted by [createRouterHistory](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/modules/createRouterHistory.js), which returns `undefined` if DOM is not defined. That's why you are having this error.

Solution is to import `useRouterHistory` and replace it somehow with `createMemoryHistory` , which intention is to be used for server side rendering. Implementation for webpack:

```
# application.js
import { Router, useRouterHistory } from "react-router"
import { createHistory } from "history"

const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({ queryKey: false })

<Router history={history}>
  ...bla-bla
</Router>

# webpack.config.server.js - sends this code to react server
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
  /createBrowserHistory/,
  require.resolve("./node_modules/react-router/lib/createMemoryHistory.js")
)
```